# Android: How to send a screenshot in an email without saving that screenshot to the SD card?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bitmap

Every example I've read for sending a screenshot via email in Android involves saving first saving the bitmap to the SD card, and then referencing the picture later to send it in an email. Is there a way that I can send the screenshot without saving it to the phone first?

Comment: How are you planning on sending the email? `ACTION_SEND`? `ACTION_SENDTO`? JavaMail? Something else?

Comment: I am using ACTION_SEND

Comment: And what's wrong with saving it and then removing it ? It actually *feels* like a better approach to me, since if, for any reason, the app crashes - it will be able to resume and send the image.

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to try creating a streaming `ContentProvider` that uses a pipe, rather than a file, for the `ParcelFileDescriptor` returned by `openFile()`. Your provider would provide the screenshot from heap space, writing to the `OutputStream` that you get from your end of the pipe. Then, you would pass a `Uri` to your provider's stream in the `EXTRA_STREAM` extra for the attachment. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/Pipe) illustrates the technique, though in my case I am reading in a file to write to the `OutputStream`.

This is a fair bit of work, and it may not be compatible with all email clients. For example, your pipe-based stream is not seekable, and clients might think they can seek in the stream to rewind to re-read in various bits. Also remember that you will still need to convert the `Bitmap` of your screenshot into a PNG file.

If your concern is having the file out on external storage, write the screenshot to internal storage and use `FileProvider` to serve it. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider) is similar to the preceding one and illustrates the use of `FileProvider`.

> first saving the bitmap to the SD card

Approximately zero examples will demonstrate this, as [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) is not readily accessible by developers. Those examples are probably demonstrating writing to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: Is there any way I could store the picture in some sort of cache and then call it from there?

Comment: @AdrianM: As noted in my answer, if your concern is having the file out on external storage, write the screenshot to internal storage and use `FileProvider` to serve it. You are welcome to have the file in `getCacheDir()`, which is part of your internal storage that `FileProvider` can serve from.